# How to let the bot to get a reason when the event on_member_ban is happened?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

This is my code

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_ban(self, guild, user: discord.User):
    db = sqlite3.connect("./data/modlog.db")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        f"SELECT channel_id FROM auditlog WHERE guild_id = {guild.id}"
    )
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        return
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Member Banning Case", colour=discord.Colour.red())
        embed.add_field(name="Member Name", value=user.name)
        embed.add_field(name="Reason", value=user.)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"User ID: {user.id}")
        embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        channel = self.client.get_channel(id=int(result[0]))
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

I want my bot to get the reason of banning, is it possible to do that?

Comment: You could call https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.fetch_ban to get the `BanEntry` which has the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When banning a user from a server you can supply a reason. It can also be empty.
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_ban#discord.Guild.ban

`on_member_ban()` is then called which you are referencing in your code:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_ban#discord.on_member_ban
With this you get the `guild` and `user` object.

Only in the audit log it says the reason for the ban. You can search your audit log.
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_ban#discord.AsyncIterator.find

```
def predicate(event):
    return event.reason is not None

event = await guild.audit_logs().find(predicate)
```

Only an example. This returns the last event that has a reason. This could be any event (user unban, user ban, message delete etc.)

The `event` variable is of an instance of this class: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_ban#discord.AuditLogEntry
which was retrieved through `Guild.audit_logs()`: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_ban#discord.Guild.audit_logs

You'll have to adjust the `predicate` method to something like:

```
def predicate(event):
    return event.action is discord.AuditLogAction.ban
```

Once you have the event object with the user ban you can extract the ban reason with `event.reason`.

(Note: I did not test this. I'm guesswriting this based on the documentation.)

---

The actual programming and testing you will have to do yourself. I gave you some guidance which methods you have to look up and use.